# How to convert String to array in Java

Tags: java, sharedpreferences

I have a string `String myStringArray = "[491174, 414529, 414557]";`. I want output `491174, 414529, 414557` just this part. I tried many methods to convert string to array and many other things. I tried something I'm adding the code below.

My Code

```
String myStringArray = "[491174, 414529, 414557]";
String newArray = myStringArray.replaceAll(" ", "");
System.out.println("Before Remove : " + newArray);

String remove = newArray.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ",");
String rm = remove.replaceFirst(",", "");

System.out.println("After Remove : " + rm);
```

**Output**

```
Before Remove : [491174,414529,414557]
After Remove : 491174,414529,414557,
```

As you can see I have `,` in the end and I don't know how to remove this `,`. Please help me if you can.

Comment: Just replace "[" and "]" with an empty string and you get what you want

Comment: Minor, but dont use `replaceAll` on the first call. Use `replace` instead. The difference is that former uses regex, latter not. Both replace all occurences. The naming is just unfortunate.

Comment: Or just cut of the first and last character from the String like  `myStringArray.substring(1, myStringArray.length() - 1)`. Note however that this String modification has absolutely nothing to do with converting a String to an Array. If you actually want to convert the String to an array (As you mention in your question) you need to do something completely different.

Comment: It looks like you just want to remove everything that is NOT digit or comma from `[491174, 414529, 414557]`. You can do that in single call `String replaced = "[491174, 414529, 414557]".replaceAll("[^\\d,]", "");`

Comment: Anyway what you seem to be doing is creating mechanism for *deserialization*. While what you have now may work for simple cases you should consider already existing mechanisms. For instance your current data can be considered as representation of JSON so with `gson` parser your code could look like `int[] ints = new Gson().fromJson(myStringArray, int[].class);`.

Comment: You don't seem to actually want to convert to an array, or at least, your attempt still produces a single string.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
rm = rm.substring(0, rm.length() - 1);
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but this is probably getting downvoted because the answer addresses the wrong problem.  You are fixing the extra comma that the OP added by using code that he should not have to begin with.  You could just substring the original `myStringArray` with similar code to what you posted here, instead of fixing the `rm` and leaving all the code that is not needed.  Also try not to post code only answers, please add explanation.